# Field labels in wrong place on Careers when adding new "other" project

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I'm on Chrome 21.0.1180.57 on Mac OS X 10.6.8.
When I add a new project to my careers profile, in the "other" category (so not github, codeplex, etc.), the labels are in weird places and hence I wound up putting my role in the technologies field.

[image: screenshot]